# How to place a `flextable` and `ggplot` side by side in `RMarkdown` or `Quarto` like in excel

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, flextable, quarto

I have a report template looks like below in Excel, and I am trying to make it into `Rmarkdown` or `Quarto`.

I have created the table with `flextable` and the graph with `ggplot` separately, but find it hard to stitch them together as below.

Any packages I should look into for this?

So far I only tried `gridExtra::grid.arrange()`, but did not look well.

[image]

Comment: What is your output format?!

Comment: @shafee it would be PDF or Word.

Answer (score 1):

In Quarto you can use `layout-ncol` chunk option to do this concisely.

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: docx
---

## Quarto

```{r}
#| echo: false
#| layout-ncol: 2

library(flextable)
flextable(head(cars)) |> 
  bold(part = "header") |> 
  add_footer_lines("The 'cars' dataset")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) + geom_point()
```
````

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This somehow works in Quarto, but still not fully satisfied when caption is included. The top of the plot in my case always align to the caption line in word rendering when `tbl-cap` is used. `flextable`'s caption is not yet supported by Quarto.

Comment: Yes, `flextable` captioning is yet to be supported. I would suggest trying other table formatting pkgs like `gt` or `kableExtra` and personally I would like to go with pdf output, since if not something is supported by quarto out of the box, *LaTeX* may be of help.

Comment: As a last resort, I just saved both as images, and put them in the :::{layout-ncol=2}